# Rewrite New Folder Path in htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I need some assistance with a rewrite rule. I browsed several posts on the topic but i did not fine one that applies to my case. I've seen rewrite rules for folders but not folder paths.

With the exception of the file names, all folders are non-existent, they are just written on the browser address field for SEO purposes. The names are obtained from my Locations database.

The current rewrite rule, adds the fake folder names "/location/" and the number of the state and city, for example:

```
    /location/georgia/atlanta/file.html
```

I made changes to my locations database and now I have all USA locations together, so now I would like for users to see:

```
    /location/usa/georgia/atlanta/file.html
```

I tried these rule but I get an 404 error message.

```
    RewriteRule ^location/tennessee/(.*) location/usa/tennessee/$1
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Please show us how your files are currently structured on the server. What I see from this example is that you are taking the wrong way around. You should use something like: `^location/usa/tennessee/(.*) location/tennessee/$1`. But I can't tell for sure unless you provide the structure in your website.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteRule   ^/location/(.*)$  /location/usa/$1  [R]
```

From an example at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to response Intermernet. unfortunately your suggestion is not working either. I added the line you suggested and I get a 404 error and this on the address field of the browsers: /location/usa/tennessee//?id=tennessee/

Comment: I think this other line is causing that: RewriteRule ^location\/(.+)$ browse_locations.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

Comment: I dont think I can change this line because if I make it a blanket rewrite, other links, like location/germany/berlin would be rewritten as location/usa/germany/berlin, causing more 404 errors.

Comment: Hmm, try just doing `RewriteRule   ^/location/$  /location/usa/  [R]`